# Core Data: Turning Objects into Faults after saving them?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my code I do a large import of thousands of objects and execute `save` after each object .

Do I need to turn each object into faults after saving it to save memory or will Core Data turn it automatically into faults? Unfortunately, I have not found any clue in [Apple`s doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html).

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A. You can turn an object into a fault with [refreshObject:mergeChanges: (NSManagedObject)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/refreshObject%3amergeChanges%3a). This will give up strong references to related objects, so that they can be released. (If they are not holded by another reference.)

> You can turn a realized object into a fault with the
>   refreshObject:mergeChanges: method. If you pass NO as the mergeChanges
>   argument, you must be sure that there are no changes to that object’s
>   relationships. If there are, and you then save the context, you will
>   introduce referential integrity problems to the persistent store.
>   ([Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001202-SW2))

B. You can wipe all objects out with [-reset (NSManagedObjectContext)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/reset) as Daniel G said. But this really wipes out the objects, references can break.

C. I think, that there is no promise of CD to turn all saved objects into faults. (Unsaved objects cannot turn into faults.) But simply overwrite [-didTurnIntoFault (NSManagedObject)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/didTurnIntoFault) to see the behavior of CD.

Comment: Do I need to turn an object into faults with `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` after it has been been saved? I thought I need `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` only for objects I have fetched and that newly inserted objects would be released / faulted automatically after being saved.

Comment: I never checked it and I do not find a documentation, too. You can easily find out with C. in my answer or by -isFault after saving the object. Anyway, turning an object into fault which is already faulted, shouldn't be that expensive.

Comment: Currently I turn the objects into faults after saving them using `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` It works, but I am not sure if this the right way to do it or if there is any "best practice" recommendation regarding saving and faulting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking but if you have a lot of objects hanging around in your context you can always use the method -[NSManagedObjectContext reset] to reset the context and purge memory. You also don't want to do this if you have any objects that reference NSManagedObjects within the recently reset context.

I'm not sure as to the nature of your application or why you would need to execute a save on thousands of objects, it seems that you should look into using batches for your fetch requests. This way core data will guarantee that only a specified number of objects will be living in the context at any given time.

I hope this helps?

Comment: This does not turn an MO into a fault, but wipes it out.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear enough: (1) "_it seems that you should look into using batches for your fetch requests_." I am not fetching objects from Core Data, I am creating new objects. Thus, fetching in batches wouldn`t help in my case. (2) `-[NSManagedObjectContext reset]`destroys objects in other contexts as well. I can't it use here. (3) My question is: Do I need to fault / release any objects newly inserted into Core Data by using `refresh:` on the managed object context or will they be released / faulted automatically after having being saved?

Comment: My apologies, now I understand. The answer is no, the objects you create will not hang around in memory unless you are maintaining strong references to them. For light reading you can look into Apples documentation on Object Lifetime Management. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMemory.html If you want to take this further I would recommend watching this years WWDC episode 211 - Core Data Performance Optimization and Debugging, its really worthwhile. Enjoy:)

Comment: Again: He did not ask, when a managed object is deleted from memory, but faulted (= the content is removed from memory).

Comment: I know, and I'm merely implying that unless you explicitly turn a relationship into a fault you cannot know for certain when an object will be faulted (Re: the answer above, using  refreshObject:mergeChanges: to explicitly create faults). Since Alex is creating and saving objects we know that they are released after the save assuming there are no references to the created objects so they can't be faults as they are not in the context... I personally wrap the object creation in an autoreleasepool...